# Java : Catch exception of variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, recursion, exception, try-catch

I am trying to create an recursive method (function). This method is handling objects of another class, each instance of which has 3 Integer fields. (Integer var1, var2 ,var3;). I was wondering if there is an exception or error of "variable might not have been initialized", so in which case the method will stop. At first, I thought it will throw nullPointerException because it is an object, but unwrapping works automatically. Is there any solution?
(I know this is a compiling error...)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Fields are default-initialized to null (if they're reference types); so you shouldn't get a compile error from what you describe. (The variable-might-not-be-initialized compile-errors are only for local variables and final fields.) Can you post your actual code?

Comment: A simple example : 
class test{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Integer x;
  System.out.println(x);
 } 
}

class test{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Integer x = null;
  System.out.println(x);
 } 
}
 
Output 1:test.java:5: error: variable x might not have been initialized
  System.out.println(x);
                     ^
1 error

Output 2:null

Comment: I think he's running into a compiler error because the parameter(s) he's passing in isn't initialized, and he's trying to bypass that compiler error with a try/catch.

Comment: @JAAAY: You can, and should, edit your question.

Comment: @ruakh You say that fields are default initialized to null, thats what I believe also. But why the 2 examples I mentioned are different?

Comment: @JAAAY: Your examples don't involve fields. ;-)

Comment: In the example if you try `System.out.println(x.toString());` or if any method is tried to accessed of it then, it will throw NullPointerException. If a non-initialized variable is passed to `System.out.println()` it will just print null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to make a check if it is an instance of the class type or not before using it. Consider following:

```
Integer x = null;
Integer y = new Integer(0);

if(x instanceof Integer)
    System.out.println("x is initialized.");
else
    System.out.println("x is NOT initialized.");

if(y instanceof Integer)
    System.out.println("y is initialized.");
else
    System.out.println("y is NOT initialized.");
```

The output will result:

x is NOT initialized.

y is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize all three variables with dummy/temporary values in the outer scope of that method, then overwrite them with whatever is being passed into your method. For example:

```
Integer myVar1 = 0;
Integer myVar2 = 0;
Integer myVar3 = 0;
public static void yourMethod(Integer var1, Integer var2, Integer var3) {
  try {
    myVar1 = var1;
    myVar2 = var2;
    myVar3 = var3;
  ... your code
  catch(NullPointerException ex) {
     // handling error code
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new Integer()` unless you need unique references.

Comment: @Jayson But how to catch an exception then?

Comment: You would just wrap your code in a try catch. I think you're confusing what kind of error you're expecting if those variables aren't initialized elsewhere. If they're never being initialized you'll get a compile error, but if you're being passed a null and you're trying to handle that, then you'll catch a different error, e.g. a null pointer. so you can't do things like var1.intValue();